# KSQL Java error when trying to create stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a topic in Kafka with data and I want to create a stream in KSQL but i keep getting an error with Java. Any ideas what may be going on? The error is (note i have replaced some of the ksql command with xxx for brevity):

> Could not write the statement 'CREATE STREAM MESSAGES_00 (xxx) WITH
> (KAFKA_TOPIC='messages',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');' into the command topic.
>
> Caused by: Could not write the statement xxx into the command topic.
>
> Caused by: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
> class     org.xerial.snappy.Snappy**
>
> Caused by: **Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy**

Any ideas what may be causing this? I am running Java Azul 11 on Mac M1.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` with message `Could not initialize class ...` says that the JVM has already tried and failed to load that class. If you go back further through the logs/output, do you get a different error message the first time the JVM tried and failed to load the class? Do you get a different error message the first time after you start Kafka?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The error is the same whenever i run the command on ksql (even when i load different topics/data). The error does not appear in any other context. Looking into logs I see this 'org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64' and 'Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappyatorg.apache.kafka.common.compress.SnappyFactory.wrapForOutput(SnappyFactory.java:38)' there are then many lines like that. Could it be the JVM I'm running or permissions I am giving?

Comment: Ok so I think it may be because the snappy.jar file i have does not have a directory for Mac m1 (only intel x86) - any ideas where I could get this file? FYI this is just an idea after looking into it

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue: The snappy.jar files in Confluent do not have M1 Mac compatibility. Download the jar files (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.8.4/) and replace the existing files (do a search to find where the snappy.jar files exist as there are multiple).

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. I've never worked with Kafka and don't have an M1 Mac. All I could really contribute to this question was that the 'Could not initialize class...' error is obscuring the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes but that pushed me in the right direction so always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue were maven unit tests were failing with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy`

This issue did not happen in my peer's non M1 processor Macbooks.

As AE93 pointed adding `snappy-java` jar in the pom dependency list resolved the issue

Ref: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/1.1.8.4

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
  <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you AE93.